# Show all values in Chart.js v2 doughnut chart tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js2

I am using [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) v2.5.0.

When a user hovers over the doughnut chart, I want the tooltip to show all values, like demostrated in the image below:

[image: tooltip with all values]

This is the code I currently have:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("chart-area").getContext("2d");
var myPie = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Dataset 1',
      data:  [
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
        randomScalingFactor(),
      ],
      backgroundColor: [
        chartColors.blue,
        chartColors.red,
        chartColors.green,
        chartColors.orange
      ],
  }],
  },
  options: {
  }
});
```

JSFiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/DUKEiLL/qkop5c9h/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can accomplish this by changing the [tooltips interaction mode](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#dataset) to "dataset":

```
options: {
    tooltips: {
        mode: "dataset"
    }
}
```

JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/qkop5c9h/4/

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Chart.js 4.1.1, and the notation slightly changed from the one in the accepted answer:

```
options: {
    interaction: {
        mode: 'dataset'
    }
}
```